# Android: How to prevent a Wifi disconnect on DHCP renewal?

Tags: android, android-wifi, dhcp

We are developing software on a custom Android platform and we begin to receive complaints from customers about the state of the Wifi connection. It seems that once in a while, they loose their Wifi connection for 1-2 seconds and then it comes back automatically. They can notice this from a small GUI feedback or from a disconnect/reconnect event issued from an XMPP client.

After investigation, we found from the log in `adb logcat` that the Wifi is changing its state from `CONNECTED` to `CONNECTING` every time there is a DHCP renewal. As we currently have a DHCP lease time of 1 hour, our platform tries to renew its address every 29 minutes. Here is a log excerpt from a DHCP renewal :

```
[ 11-24 10:10:11.751  2629: 3350 D/DhcpStateMachine ]
DHCP renewal on wlan0

[ 11-24 10:10:12.351  2629: 3350 D/DhcpStateMachine ]
DHCP succeeded on wlan0

[ 11-24 10:10:12.361  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
onReceive: action=android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE

[ 11-24 10:10:12.361  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION: mIsWifiConnected=false

[ 11-24 10:10:12.361  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION: networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/VERIFYING_POOR_LINK, reason: (unspecified), extra: "XXX", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true

[ 11-24 10:10:12.371  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
onReceive: action=android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE

[ 11-24 10:10:12.371  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION: mIsWifiConnected=false

[ 11-24 10:10:12.371  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION: networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK, reason: (unspecified), extra: "XXX", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true

[ 11-24 10:10:12.381  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
onReceive: action=android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE

[ 11-24 10:10:12.381  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION: mIsWifiConnected=true

[ 11-24 10:10:12.381  2877: 2877 D/DCT      ]
NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION: networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "XXX", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
```

How could I prevent the connection state to change from `CONNECTED` to `CONNECTING` while using DHCP ? Can I change a setting somewhere to change this behaviour ?

Comment: What version of Android is the affected device running?

Comment: I was expecting this: https://www.net.princeton.edu/android/android-stops-renewing-lease-keeps-using-IP-address-11236.html but it affected much older devices.

Comment: Could be related to [Issue 11236](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11236)?

Comment: @atok, CKD Publishing: unfortunately, it does not seem related to this problem.

Comment: I do not think you can prevent the system from sending you these events, but you can change how you react to the event by ignoring CONNECTING.

Comment: I don't understand why if Lease Time is 1 hour, you have renewals every 29 mins (is this the real problem?) . Besides, I think it's a very short value compared to a typical value of several hours or days, and don't see anything  strange in the client reconnecting the network interface when the lease expires: the IP address changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `DISCONNECTING` can be really avoided. The only way to deal with this issue is ignoring the `DISCONNECTING` state on a Wifi change state and to use the [`isConnectedOrConnecting`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnectedOrConnecting()) method from `Network` instead of [`isConnected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()) to verify if we are connected or not.